# comparing values in a list to create a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm trying to append my list into a dictionary based on an if condition. I wrote a working function for this problem, but I want to write this program in **list comprehension**.

The below function organizes all the tracks by month. The result will be a dictionary with the month as the key and the tracks as the value.

```
[[j for j in lst2] for i in month if j[-2] == i] 
#I tried this list comprehension code for my function given below
```

column names
     [Position, Track Name, Artist, Streams, Datetime.object, Region, month, day]

```
 Input : #my working code

[['1','Starboy','The Weeknd','3135625',datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0),
  'global',1,1],
 ['2','Closer','The Chainsmokers','3015525',datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0),
  'global',1,1]
 ['3','Party Monster','The Weeknd','829599',datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 2, 0, 0),
'  global',2,2]]

def organized(lst2):
    month = [1,2]
    edict = {}
    for i in month:
        elst = []
        for j in lst2:
            if j[-2] == i:
                elst.append(j)
        edict[i] = elst
    return edict

output

{1: [['1', 'Starboy', 'The Weeknd', '3135625',
        datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0),'global', 1, 1],
     ['2', 'Closer', 'The Chainsmokers', '3015525',                        
        datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'global', 1, 1]]
 2:[[‘3’, 'Party Monster', 'The Weeknd', '829599',
        datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 2, 0, 0), 'global', 2, 2]]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output is a `dict`, so you'll need a `dict` comprehension (with a `list` comprehension nested in it):

```
def organized(lst2):
    month = [1, 2]
    return {i: [j for j in lst2 if j[-2] == i] for i in month}
```